# PDO login script Fatal Error

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

So I am creating my login system using PDO which I am new to, hit a bit of a snag, I am getting a fatal error when trying to login with the users details. It appears to work If I type in random bits and will fail correctly, yet if I put in thr right details I get the Fatal error.

Here is my script:

```
class User{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }

    public function Login($emailAddress, $pass){
        if(!empty($emailAddress) && !empty($pass)) {
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailAddress=? and pass=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $emailAddress);
            $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st->execute();


            if($st->rowCount() == 1){
                echo"User verified, Access granted.";
            } else{
                echo "Incorrect email address or password";
            }


        }else{
            echo "Please enter email and password!";
        }
    }

}
```

I have a few more columns on top of emailAddress and pass but I am not sure if this is where the conflict is?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardR/user.php on line 18

```
<?php

class Connection{

    public function dbConnect() {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dashboardr","****","****");
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you also post the code that is working ?

Comment: `$this->db->dbConnect()` is not returning a viable database connection.

Comment: How do you mean? that is the action script for the form, the only bit that executes is the else statement if you fail to put anything in the fields.

Comment: @castis - Is that what the issue is? As I am VERY new could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm assuming `dbConnect()` is used to connect to the database and then return an object that can be used to run queries. You tried to call `$this->db->prepare()` but the error says `$this->db` is not an object. This most likely means that `$this->db->dbConnect()` is failing and probably returning either `null`, `false`, or something close to it. Make sure all your db credentials are correct and that you can successfully connect to it.

Comment: @castis I have a full connection to the DB and a valid one at that, check my Question and see my connection script.

Comment: Set PDO to throw exceptions to debug more easily:
    
 `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dashboardr","****","****");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: You having a valid connection is irrelevant, `$this->db` is still not an instance of PDO, which is the cause of your error.